# AVAudioPlayer AudioToolbox AudioSessionPropertyListeners Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash, avaudioplayer

I keep getting this crash in an app that reuses an AVAudioPlayer contained in a singleton class to play different songs.

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at
AudioToolbox
AudioSessionPropertyListeners::CallPropertyListenersImp(unsigned int, unsigned int, void const*)
```

Maybe I do not deallocate things properly. Does anyone have any clue or encountered a similar crash before before?

**Declaration**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

**Deallocation**

```
- (void)dealloc
{
     _player.delegate = nil;
     _player = nil;
}
```

**Reuse**

```
if(_player) {
    [_player stop];
    _player.delegate = nil;
    _player = nil;
}

NSError *error = nil;
_player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL error:&error];
_player.numberOfLoops = -1;
_player.delegate = self;
[_player play];
```